# Asp.Net Dependency question

Tags: asp.net, dll, bin

I have a dll, call it dllA and dllA references dllB. When I put dllA in the bin folder of my asp.net application, and call a method in dllA that references dllB, the asp.net application throws an error saying can't find dllB. I have to add dllB to the asp.net bin folder as well. My question is why, if I'm only referencing classes from dllB from dllA, do I have to add dllB in the bin folder along with dllA?

Comment: Maybe I don't get your idea... how do you expect dlla to access dllb if dllb it's not visible?

Comment: Well, it very possible I don't get it, but in my reference folder in DllA, I've including a reference to DLLB. I kinda thought that if it's in the reference folder, I would be able to access it.

Comment: The reference is only a pointer, so the file still needs to be accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reference in dllA from dllB, how is dllA going to call that reference without a copy of dllB?

Every assembly that has code that is excuted on your page either needs to be in the bin folder for your asp.net app or in the GAC.